# R Shiny check function not triggering value function

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I'm trying to use `ReactivePoll` to update a data frame. The check function is supposed to return different values when a) new rows are added to database tables and b) `input$type` changes.

```
# checks to see if input$type has changed or the table corresponding to input$type has grown
check.data <- function() {
    row.count <- 0
    if (data.connection$source == "pg") {
        pg.connection$connection <- dbConnect(pg.connection$driver, dbname = pg.settings.database(), host = pg.settings.host(), port = as.integer(pg.settings.port()), user = pg.settings.user(), password = pg.settings.password())
        row.count <- as.integer(dbGetQuery(pg.connection$connection, paste0("SELECT count(*) FROM ", input$type ,"datum")))
        dbDisconnect(pg.connection$connection)
    }
    print(row.count)    # make sure return value is changing when it should
    row.count
}
# refreshes data
refresh.data <- function() {
    print("check")      # check if function is executing
    frame <- data.frame()
    if (data.connection$source == "pg") {
        pg.connection$connection <- dbConnect(pg.connection$driver, dbname = pg.settings.database(), host = pg.settings.host(), port = as.integer(pg.settings.port()), user = pg.settings.user(), password = pg.settings.password())
        frame <- dbReadTable(pg.connection$connection, paste0(input$type, "datum"))
        dbDisconnect(pg.connection$connection)
    }
    frame
}
data <- reactivePoll(15000, NULL, check.data, refresh.data)
```

According to R Shiny's documentation, "the check function indicates change by returning a different value from the previous time it was called." I've verified that `row.count` is changing, but "check" is never printed, implying the value function never executes. I know row counting isn't a reliable way to check for change (tables may have the same number of rows), but `row.count` *is* changing.

Comment: Do you have something that needs `data()`? Like `observe(print(data()))`? I ask because the `data` reactive could be invalidated, but doesn't flush, since no observer needs its value.

Comment: @ K. Rohde That did it! I didn't know you needed to use the data in order for it to work and didn't think to check. Thanks much